# Do wordpress create a new file for each new post?

Tags: php

Assume that I have a wordpress blog website.My question is,do wordpress create a new php file for each post I create or does it simply inserts to database and fetchs from database by query string?
I read that it stores posts in database.But is it SEO-friendly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking several questions:

1. **Does WP create a new PHP file for each post?** No, it does not. Your statement, "[insert] a database [record]," is correct. The record it creates for a post (and also many other post types) is in the `wp_posts` (your prefix may not be `wp_`) table.
2. **Is it SEO-friendly?** This is a much more complicated question. The short answer is, "yes," but only if you get a lot of other things right.

There are times when WP *uses* a separate PHP file for a particular post (look [in the Codex under Theme Development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development)) but WP does not normally *create* any PHP files.

It seems that you think that having an individual PHP file for a post and the post being SEO-friendly are related. This is not really the case. Search engines don't really care much about the physical implementation of your website, just the HTML that's created.

There are many resources on making your site SEO-friendly. Most of the work is between the theme and the content on the site but there are many plugins that can help you.

This is a fairly complicated subject and specific methods change over time. If you can't find a good plugin that addresses your needs you may consider consulting a person or firm with SEO expertise to help.

Do know that a *significant* portion of the Internet runs WP and it is definitely possible to make WP SEO-friendly without a lot of modification. Also keep in mind that many SEO plugins are some of the most-used plugins in WP and therefore some of the most frequently attacked.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is just pushing one record into the database.
And about SEO friendly is or not depends upon the quality wording you have written in your post. And the images also matters a lot in this case. If you want a make a post SEO friendly make sure you are writing the image description, alt text, etc.

Comment: Thanks for further information.Why I wonder this was because I have a website build from scratch called https://www.sosyosapien.com  and I was confused about how to store posts that members post.Now I store it in database like wo do.But I dont know how to fill alt tags while images are being shared by members